# Issue in fetching values from child window

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I closed a fancy box and want to redirect to other page wih parametes which I got from fancybox controller.But as I  close the fancybox it says i cant use those parametes value
Erro is :   CS0103: The name 'CID' does not exist in the current context

herei is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var CSec = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["Clientseckey"]));
        var CID =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["ClientID"]));
        parent.closeFancybox(); 
        var csec1 =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["Clientseckey"]));
        var url = '@Url.Action("NewAPIForm", "Developer", new { clientID = CID }, new { clientkey = CSec1  })';
        parent.location.href = url;
    });

</script>
```

CS0103: The name 'CID' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Please show your actual HTML output. Your server-side code is not helpful for a client-side issue.

Comment: Here is the error is that what you are asking as this si the code I wrote in view: Compilation Error

Comment: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'CID' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

Comment: Line 15:         var csec1 =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["Clientseckey"]));
Line 16:          var CID =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["ClientID"]));
Line 17:         var url = '@Url.Action("NewAPIForm", "Developer", new { clientID = CID }, new { clientkey = CSec1  })';
Line 18:         parent.location.href = url;
Line 19:     });

Comment: '@Url.Action' is not part of JavaScript - that's your server side code.

Comment: Sorry I made different so many comments because it doesn't allow in one comment because of limit character

Comment: But it worked fine when I was using without parameters

Comment: It worked when I used like this:     var url = '@Url.Action("NewAPIForm", "Developer", new { clientID = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["ClientID"])), clientkey =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["Clientseckey"])) })';

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having with scope is because `CID` is a javascript variable which you are trying to use as a server side variable.

So instead of `new {clientId = CID}` try `new { clientId = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempDate["Clientseckey"]))}`

Or place the CID in a server side variable:

```
@{
  var CID2 = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempDate["Clientseckey"]));
}
```

(I called it CID2 to make the difference easier to spot below)
Then in the JS you can do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var CSec = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["Clientseckey"]));
        var CID =  @CID2;
        parent.closeFancybox(); 
        var csec1 =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["Clientseckey"]));
        var url = '@Url.Action("NewAPIForm", "Developer", new { clientID = CID2 }, new { clientkey = CSec1  })';
        parent.location.href = url;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me.I used   var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("NewAPIForm", "Developer", new { ClientSecret = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["Clientseckey"])), clientID = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["ClientID"])), AppName = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["appname"])), Email = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["email"])) }))';

Comment: But why all my values shows in double quotes: like                           http://Developer/NewAPIForm?ClientSecret=%22aKX4AVtc0VmNIlnD2SwuxP5PdeRMYzMR4QZWIXN0OsQCkTMO%22&clientID=%22AP-J2UHYDMQ%22&AppName=%22Test%22&Email=%22a%40gmail.com%22